# MSSQL - Setting up simple Replication fails

Tags: sql-server, replication

Heads up: I'm a rookie when it comes to SQL Administration.

Im seting up a simple MSSQL Replication running server '19 (developer edition).

The server and agent services run as local admin on the machine.
I created a small DB with just a table and a couple of rows which I would like to replicate to the same server (just a different DB).

The destribution is setup to impersonate a the service process account and the snapshot share is just a local folder.

I creted a new transactional Publication and set all the accounts to run as the Agent Account (or just impersonate).

Now I added a subscription (push), picking an empty DB and setting everything up to run as Agent Account or imersonate to the process account.

Checking the status of the syncronization, will end up in "Agent Starting". After a while I'll get an error;

```
Agent 'XXX\SRV1-Source-3' is retrying after an error. 4 retries attempted. See agent job history in the Jobs folder for more details.
```

But the Verbose of this Job is just that:

```
2019-12-12 13:42:56.651 Microsoft SQL Server Log Reader Agent 15.0.2000.5
2019-12-12 13:42:56.652 Copyright (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation
2019-12-12 13:42:56.652 Microsoft SQL Server Replication Agent: logread
2019-12-12 13:42:56.653 
2019-12-12 13:42:56.653 The timestamps prepended to the output lines are expressed in terms of UTC time.
2019-12-12 13:42:56.654 User-specified agent parameter values:
            -Publisher XXX\SRV1
            -PublisherDB Source
            -Distributor XXX\SRV1
            -DistributorSecurityMode 1
            -Continuous
            -OutputVerboseLevel 2
            -Output C:\ReplOutput.txt
            -XJOBID 0xF855F65C5625C2439F8D41552D5F0C0C
            -XJOBNAME XXX\SRV1-Source-3
            -XSTEPID 2
            -XSUBSYSTEM LogReader
            -XSERVER KNWORK\SRV1
            -XCMDLINE 0
            -XCancelEventHandle 0000000000001A58
            -XParentProcessHandle 0000000000001A80
2019-12-12 13:42:56.661 Status: 0, code: 20015, text: ''.
2019-12-12 13:42:56.662 Disconnecting from OLE DB  ''
```

Could anyone provide some more insight?

**EDIT**: The Snapshot job fails with a more specific error message, which I can't explain:

```
2019-12-12 14:31:13.079 Microsoft SQL Server Distribution Agent 15.0.2000.5
2019-12-12 14:31:13.141 Copyright (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation
2019-12-12 14:31:13.174 Microsoft SQL Server Replication Agent: distrib
2019-12-12 14:31:13.206 
2019-12-12 14:31:13.226 The timestamps prepended to the output lines are expressed in terms of UTC time.
2019-12-12 14:31:13.237 User-specified agent parameter values:
            -Subscriber XXX\SRV1
            -SubscriberDB Dest1
            -Publisher XXX\SRV1
            -Distributor XXX\SRV1
            -DistributorSecurityMode 1
            -Publication T4
            -PublisherDB Source
            -Continuous
            -OutputVerboseLevel 2
            -Output C:\ReplOutput2.txt
            -XJOBID 0x0D26D00FF5848B42BA332C3579C7D1C0
            -XJOBNAME XXX\SRV1-Source-T4-XXX\SRV1-11
            -XSTEPID 2
            -XSUBSYSTEM Distribution
            -XSERVER XXX\SRV1
            -XCMDLINE 0
            -XCancelEventHandle 0000000000001A34
            -XParentProcessHandle 0000000000001A58
2019-12-12 14:31:13.240 Startup Delay: 3407 (msecs)
2019-12-12 14:31:16.649 Connecting to Distributor 'XXX\SRV1'
2019-12-12 14:31:16.650 Connecting to OLE DB Distributor at datasource: 'XXX\SRV1', location: '', catalog: '', providerstring: '' using provider 'MSOLEDBSQL'
2019-12-12 14:31:16.654 Agent message code 20084. The process could not connect to Distributor 'XXX\SRV1'.
```

Comment: Did the snapshot agent ran successfully?

Comment: nope, but I can't convice it to give me any output. The "OutputVerboseLevel" option seems not to have any effect at all.

Comment: Is the snapshot job failing with the same error? Or some other error?

Comment: Got it to talk to me... it can't connect to the server...?

Comment: what do you have inside this file: `C:\ReplOutput.txt`?
`The process could not connect to Distributor 'XXX\SRV1'.` this message tells me that most likely the account you are using does not have the required permissions.

Comment: C:\ReplOutput.txt contains the LogJob log. The account is actually sysadmin on the DB and local admin on the machine. Also it is in the PAL of the Agent and I even disabled the firewall. I also changed the sql service and agent to use the same account and everywhere I can, I use impersonation....